# Sending a POST request with JSONArray using Volley

Tags: android, json, request, android-volley

I want to send a simple POST request in Android with a body equaling this :

```
[
 {
  "value": 1
 }
]
```

I tried to use Volley library in Android, and this is my code :

```
// the jsonArray that I want to POST    
String json = "[{\"value\": 1}]";
JSONArray jsonBody = null;
try {
     jsonBody = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                              }
final JSONArray finalJsonBody = jsonBody;

// starting the request
final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
JsonObjectRequest request = 
new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST,"https://...",null,

new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
Log.d("mytag", "Response is: " + response);}},
new Response.ErrorListener() {

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Log.d("Mytag", "error");}}) {

@Override
protected  Map<String,String> getParams() {
// the problem is here...
return (Map<String, String>) finalJsonBody;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError  {
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
// I put all my headers here like the following one : 
params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");                                    
return params;}};

queue.add(request);
```

The problem is that the getParams method only accepts a Map object since I want to send a JSONArray. So, I'm obliged to use a cast, which generate an error then...

I don't know how can I fix that 
Thank you

Comment: Read [my asnwer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197615/volley-send-jsonobject-to-server-with-post-method/32216762#32216762). However, your json is JSONArray, not JSONObject.

Comment: can you be more explicite? I still fail to code this jsonArray... thank you for your comprehension

Comment: JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{\"value\": 1}"); a JSONObject starts with { and ends with }. Moreover, what is the error message did you get? Pls post it and any logcat info if available.

Comment: thanks man, I finally resolved this part since I use a JSONArray. But I get another error due to the getparams method...

Comment: Pls post it and any logcat info if available. Moreover, overrid getBody instead of getParams for POST body params

Comment: I edited my initial post. The error is from the "getParams" method which required a Map object. But in my case, I want to send "finalJsonBody" which is a JSONAray... I hope it's clear for you ?

Comment: Try override getBody instead of getParams for POST body params

Comment: If you want to send JSONArray as params, try using Google's official volley (git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) the use their JsonArrayRequest

Comment: But it's what I'm trying to do. I don't know how can I send a JSONArray that's it. I'm trying to override getBody as you say but it's not obvious..

Comment: So, what is the error message did you get? Can you post server side code that processes your request?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean know. You talk about JsonArrayRequest  while I'm using JsonObjectRequest. I don't find any useful tutorial or example about JsonArrayRequest...

Comment: Not much different but the response :-)

Comment: Can you PLEASE tell me how can I override getBody in my example ? Or at least how can I get the server response. Because in my current code, I only got "error" as you can guess from my code

Comment: Sorry, I am on mobile now, so please see my answer link I commented above or you can look at my other answers about Volley available in SO before (view my profile, then my answers). Response from server: if success, onResponse will be called; if error, onErrorResponse called

Comment: I looked in JsonArrayRequest in your link, but apparently, you can't do a POST with it, you can only do a get. It seems too complicated (while my request is not really as difficult as that). Can you help me please ? (with the getbody or anything else, all what I want is to do this request), you are the only one who had answered me...

Comment: Please wait until tomorrow, however, please post your server-side code if available

Comment: The only error that I get is that : "com.android.volley.ServerError"  (I get that with : Log.d("Mytag", "error is  " + error);

Comment: Use parseNetworkError to find out more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to my following sample code:

**UPDATE for your pastebin link:**

Because the server responses a **`JSONArray`**, I use `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`. And no need to override `getBody` anymore.

```
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String url = "https://api.orange.com/datavenue/v1/datasources/2595aa553d3049f0b0f03fbaeaa7ddc7/streams/9fe5edb1c76e4968bdcc9c902010bc6c/values";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String jsonString = "[\n" +
                " {\n" +
                "  \"value\": 1\n" +
                " }\n" +
                "]";
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    mTextView.setText(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mTextView.setText(error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("X-OAPI-Key","TQEEGSk8OgWlhteL8S8siKao2q6LIGdq");
                    headers.put("X-ISS-Key","2b2dd0d9dbb54ef79b7ee978532bc823");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My code works for both Google's official volley libray and mcxiaoke's library

If you want to use **Google**'s library, after you git clone as Google documentation, copy **android** folder from `\src\main\java\com` (of Volley project that you cloned) to `\app\src\main\java\com` of your project as the following screenshot:

[image]

The `build.gradle` should contain the following

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'    
}
```

If your project uses **mcxiaoke**'s library, the `build.gradle` will look like the following (pay attention to `dependencies`):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.samplevolley"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

I suggest that you will create 2 new sample projects, then one will use **Google**'s library, the other will use **mcxiaoke**'s library.

**END OF UPDATE**

```
        String url = "http://...";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String jsonString = "[\n" +
                " {\n" +
                "  \"value\": 1\n" +
                " }\n" +
                "]";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // do something...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // do something...
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return jsonString.getBytes(PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                            jsonString, PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

The following screenshot is what server-side web service received:

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and I get an error related to "PROTOCOL_CHARSET". It tells me : 'PROTOCOL_CHARSET' has private access in com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest

Comment: I guess that your project uses volley library by `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'` in build.gradle file. My project uses Google's official volley library. You can replace PROTOCOL_CHARSET by "utf-8"

Comment: I am still getting an error : com.android.volley.ServerError. Perhaps it's due to volley library which is badly programmed?? Perhaps it will be a solution to take the google one?

Comment: I think you should override parseNetworkError to find out more error details. You should also check your server-side app to see how it processed your request.

Comment: I think it's better to work with the google library instead of mcxiaoke one. Do you know how can I find their .jar directly ? (I did a git clone in my Mac but after that I always get an error after the android start project command and it's very frustrating). Testing google library will be my last attempt^^

Comment: I don't use jar file. After you git clone as Google documentation, copy android folder inside \src\main\java\com (of Volley project that you cloned) into \app\src\main\java\com of your project. About mcxiaoke's volley, I used it already, it is good too :-)

Comment: This is the request that I want to send : http://pastebin.com/wt4ndxvH  Can you please test if it works for you or not? please. Thank you!!!

Comment: Ok, I will test tomorrow. You can also do your own test by a very helpful tool. That is [Postman for Chrome](https://www.getpostman.com)

Comment: Ah no no, unfortunately it's not the case yet. I'm waiting for you to test if you can post the request that i showed you (i said thank you -by politeness- for all your help), but unfortunately the problem is still occuring. Sorry if my precedent message was ambiguous

Comment: I have tested as your pastepin link, it works. Here is [the screenshot link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HGUM4c0YwpQXY5Y1MzLS1nb2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So, you need to add X-OAPI-Key and X-ISS-Key in the headers of the volley request.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I don't have android studio now. So, I can't test that before Monday. But I have faith this time, there is no reason to not work. Again, thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't worry, I often test OK before posting answer :-)

Comment: I tried your code since 2 hours and guess what. It still doesn't work for me, it will get me crazy... Here is my code : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/990905error1.png and here is the error message that i get in android studio : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/246513error2.png.  In my opinion, it's due to the wrong library that i choose to work with, i should try the google one to fix this problem, what do you think please?

Comment: Can you please tell me what import have you used, please? I'm so so confused. I used some like these : import com.android.volley.RequestQueue or import com.android.volley.Response. So it's the google library and not the mcxiaoke one no????

Comment: YES, YES, YES, it finally works. Thank you so so so so so much, really THANK you man !

Comment: Glad my answer could help you!

Comment: Can you tell me your email PLEASE? I just want to ask about an Android project (which is very very urgent because I have to finish it before this friday :( Thanks !

Comment: My email z10.blackberry@outlook.com :)

Comment: @BNK I saw your profile and I feel you might be able to help me the problem is  I am sending some json data to mysql database using volley but the value of my last entry updates all the other values inside the database. This is a link to my code http://pastebin.com/DGVQkNJC

Comment: @anup I cannot find where you call "insertToDb" inside your code. However, IMO, you should create a new question in S.O instead comments here, because perhaps there will be many other comments beside above ones.

Comment: Exactly what I needed :)

Comment: hi , I used your suggested, but it gives com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException error.

Comment: @SAndroidD check the connection from your phone to the web server/web service address, or you can search more in StackOverflow about that exception

Comment: connection is fine .when I use 1.0 version it working fine,but when I use 1.0.17 version it throws following error 'com.android.volley.NoConnectionError'

Comment: @SAndroidD you can try with 1.0.19 at https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley, however, as his notice `this project is deprecated and no longer being maintained...`