# Volley Not Sending POST data

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-volley

My Volley code is not sending the data put in PMap (a HashMap of place data). The server just receives a blank request.

I wrote this HashMap code just as I wrote it in my other app with my Volley code, and it worked fine in that app. The only difference is that this is a JSONArrayRequest, and it was a StringRequest I used in the other app.

```
RequestQueue PlaceQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonArrayRequest PlaceArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            int i;
            ArrayList<String> MArrList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> PlaceList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        MArrList.add(response.get(i).toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            JSONObject TestJobj = null;
            try {
                for (i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    TestJobj = new JSONObject(MArrList.get(i));
                    PlaceList.add(TestJobj.get("PlaceName").toString() + "\n" + "Estimated Price: $" + TestJobj.get("EstimatedPrice").toString() + ".\n" + TestJobj.get("PlaceAddress").toString() + "\n" + TestJobj.get("OtherDetails").toString());
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                DisplayHotels(PlaceList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Toast VerrorToast = Toast.makeText(context, "Connection failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            VerrorToast.show();
        }
    }) {
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> PMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            PMap.put("PlaceType", placetype);
            PMap.put("PlaceCity", placelocation);
            return PMap;
        }
    };

    PlaceQueue.add(PlaceArrayRequest);
```

The server is responding, but I just need to send the PlaceType and PlaceCity.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you placeType and placeLocation variables populated?

Comment: Refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745400/sending-a-post-request-with-jsonarray-using-volley)

Comment: e4c5: I'm not sure yet, but the field names weren't sent either, so isn't just the variables.

Comment: BNK: Which part of your answer?