# Android Volley Post Looping

Tags: android, android-volley

I've code like this

```
String url = "http://192.168.10.10/post/data.php";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("respond");
            String  codeid = jsonResponse.getString("CodeID");
            Log.d("CodeID", codeid);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}
) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Product> product = dataSource.getAllProduct();

        for (Product bk : product) {
            params.put("code1", bk.getCode1());
            params.put("code2", bk.getCode2());

        }
        return params;
    }
};
Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
```

I've data in database (about 10 row) and want to send all of row via post. With code above I'm able to send POST but only 1 row.

I've tried using for

```
            for (int i=0; i<=product.size(); i++ )
            {

            }
```

as replacement for

```
for (Product bk : product)
```

still no luck. Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: try having different key for values in get params

Comment: something like--                                                                                                   for (int i = 0; i <= product.size(); i++) {
            params.put(i + "_code1", bk.getCode1());
            params.put(i + "_code2", bk.getCode2());
        }

Comment: A little issue unrelated with your problem: your `for` loop should stop just before `product.size()`, the condition should be `i < product.size()`. Your collection has `product.size()` elements, but you start at `0`, not `1`.

Comment: @RaviGadipudi which key? I've change the key to something like "code" + i that still not working because It send all params in one long POST

subhash similiar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32827511/android-volley-post-looping?noredirect=1#comment53505541_32827703 

Kernald thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a HashMap, this is somewhat like a key-value pair.
When iterating over `product` you are assingning new values for the same keys (`"code1"` and `"code2"`). So your url may is correct, but your params get always overwritten.
Debug your code, you should observe that `params` has always 2 items at max.

You could also try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= product.size(); i++) {
    Product myProduct = product.get(i);
    params.put("product" + i + "_code1", myProduct.getCode1());
    params.put("product" + i + "_code2", myProduct.getCode2());
}
```

But this would be not a very good approach.

You may would be better of with this:

```
ArrayList<Product> products = dataSource.getAllProduct();
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= products.size(); i++) {
    Product product = products.get(i);
    String key = "product" + i;
    String value = URLEncoder.encode("code1=" + product.getCode1() + "&" +
                                     "code2=" + product.getCode2(), "UTF-8");
    params.put(key, value);
}

return params;
```

`URLEncoder.encode` will urlencode your product-String. This is needed because the url could get messed up with all the `&`. With encode those will be `&amp;`

You will be in the need do `decode` them again on the other end!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that still not working, because params send all data in one POST.

ex : 
product1_code2=2&product0_code2=1&product2_code3=3

I expected the result send  through looping
first loop send : product1_code2=2
second loop send : product0_code2=1
etc . ..

Comment: @CSemu: why don't you use a JSONArray instead HashMap

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745400/sending-a-post-request-with-jsonarray-using-volley/32775920#32775920). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.I put all my arraylist in a separate java file Common and fetched from there and put it into a new arraylist.On the server side I had a JSON array accepting multiple values for keys This should work for you all well.
 {

```
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
         ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
         ArrayList<String> arrayList2=new ArrayList<>();

        for(String s : Common.myProduct1){//myProduct1 has ur contents for getCode1()
            arrayList.add(s);
        }

        for(String s: Common.myProduct2){//myProduct2 has ur contents for getCode2()
            arrayList2.add(s);
        }


        Log.v("Params:",params.toString());
 params.put("key1",arrayList.toString().replace("[","".replace("]","")));
            params.put("key2",arrayList2.toString().replace("[","".replace("]","")));

        return params;
    }
};
```