# Post jsonarray obtained to php using volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I have jsonarray like the below format:

```
[{
    "product_id": "3",
    "model": "Carrot Pudding With Vanilla Ice Cream",
    "image": "Shivamogga\/56\/carrot Pudding with Vanilla Ice Cream.jpg",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "63.0000",
    "total": "63.0000",
    "seller_id": "485"
}, {
    "product_id": "4",
    "model": "Cheesy Baby Corn L",
    "image": "Shivamogga\/56\/cheesy Baby corn l.jpg",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "430.0000",
    "total": "430.0000",
    "seller_id": "485"
}]
```

I am getting the above jsonarray from an url. I want to post this again to a php file using volley. How to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745400/sending-a-post-request-with-jsonarray-using-volley this link will help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745400/sending-a-post-request-with-jsonarray-using-volley
duplicate of this