# Send Data to Server. in loop (Present in Sqlite Database.)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I send my Data to my cloud server... which works fine. but i want to send all data which is present in SQlite db Table. i use Do while loop under Map method but it only send only one line. not whole.

```
String url = "http://blhc.com:1980/Mob/SendDoc.aspx";

SendDoctors(Context paramContext)
{
    this.cont = paramContext;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    //region Sending
    try{
        ds = new DataSource(cont);
        ds.open();
        final Cursor cursor = ds.send();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {
            //region Sending Data
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(cont,"Uploaded.." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Log.v("jarvis" ,"Resposce" + response);
                        }
                    }
                    , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(cont,"Error.." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    param.put("CELL_NO", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_PHONE_NUM)));
                    param.put("M_DATE", M_DATE);
                    param.put("M_TIME", M_TIME);
                    param.put("EMP_ID", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_EMP_ID)));
                    param.put("DOC_ID", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_DOC_ID)));
                    param.put("SA", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_SA)));
                    param.put("NOTE", "NOTE");
                    param.put("CO_ID", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_CO_ID)));
                    param.put("LAT", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_LOC_LAT)));
                    param.put("LNG", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_LOC_LON)));
                    param.put("USER_ID", String.valueOf(LoginActivity.ID));
                    return param;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getmInstance(cont).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
            //endregion
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }catch(Exception e){}
    //endregion

    return null;
}
```

**ERROR**

```
E/Volley: [191] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 requested, with a size of 6
          android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 requested, with a size of 6
              at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
              at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
              at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
              at com.example.zed.androidapplication.SendDoctors$3.getParams(SendDoctors.java:84)
              at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:468)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
              at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
              at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
W/System.err: com.android.volley.VolleyError: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 requested, with a size of 6
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:143)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 requested, with a size of 6
W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
W/System.err:     at com.example.zed.androidapplication.SendDoctors$3.getParams(SendDoctors.java:84)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:468)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

apply the Loop. But it Shows me some error...That I exceeded the limit.

one thing i have to clear thar On my web Server An Api take Variables not the array.. Now I thoink i clear my point?

Note: I am using volley lib to send data to server.

Thanks In advance. Really appreciate you help.

Comment: first prepare your whole local data map object and then you will call the volley request.

Comment: try to loop doInBackground

Comment: Request to server inside a loop is not a good idea. What happens if your `Cursor` have 1000 row or more? it will send request lot of request to server. Try with a single request and send all data in array or list.

Comment: @AbuYousuf how can i do this?

Comment: @AbuYousuf Bro plz take a look. my prob is i cannot send my data in Array. I have to send in Variable because of the receiving End.

Comment: The `error` you have posted its about database not network. If your server accepts a `variable` then convert `JsonArray` to `JsonObject` or try using `JsonObjectRequest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my Problem. Thanks all Of you. 
I post my answer of my Above code. and it works fine.

```
    //region Sending
    try{
        ds = new DataSource(cont);
        ds.open();
        final Cursor cursor = ds.send();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        do {

            //region Sending Variables
            final String CELL_NO = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_PHONE_NUM));
            final String M_DATE = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_DATE));
            final String M_TIME =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_TIME));
            final String EMP_ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_EMP_ID));
            final String UserID = String.valueOf(LoginActivity.ID) ;
            final String DOC_ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_DOC_ID));
            final String SA= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_SA));
            final String NOTE = " - ";
            final String CO_ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_CO_ID));
            final String LAT =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_LOC_LAT));
            final String LNG=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_DA_LOC_LON));
            //endregion

            //region Sending Data
            Log.v("jarvis","Line = 1");
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            ds.updateStatus(DOC_ID,M_DATE,M_TIME,EMP_ID); //true
                            Toast.makeText(cont,"Uploaded And Saved.." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.v("jarvis","Line = 2");
                        }
                    }
                    , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v("jarvis","Line = 3");
                    ds.updateFalse(DOC_ID,M_DATE,M_TIME,EMP_ID); //true
                    Toast.makeText(cont,"Error.." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Log.v("jarvis","Line = 4");

                    Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    param.put("CELL_NO", CELL_NO);
                    param.put("M_DATE", M_DATE);
                    param.put("M_TIME", M_TIME);
                    param.put("EMP_ID", EMP_ID);
                    param.put("DOC_ID", DOC_ID);
                    param.put("SA", SA);
                    param.put("NOTE", NOTE);
                    param.put("CO_ID", CO_ID );
                    param.put("LAT", LAT);
                    param.put("LNG",LNG);
                    param.put("USER_ID",UserID);
                    return param;
                }
            };
            Log.v("jarvis","Line = 5");
            MySingleton.getmInstance(cont).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
            //endregion
            Log.v("jarvis","Line = 6");

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }catch(Exception e){}
    //endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is the reference for you to getData from Sqlite and call volley and hit API every time :

```
 private void UploadSavedData() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME_COUNT;
    db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.e("DATA_CHECK","DATA_CHECK");
        do {
            countEditQuantity(cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3)); //calling webservices here
            Log.e("DATASQLA",""+cursor.getString(1));



        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }else{

    }

}


 public void countEditQuantity(final String skuData, final String newQty) {
   String url = Constants.EDIT_TAKE_INVENTORY_URL"+dcId+"&sku="+""+skuData+"&new_qty="+""+newQt;
    Log.e("URL",""+url);

    StringRequest eventoReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", response.toString());

                    if (progressCount <= 1) {
                        if(databaseHelper.deleteTableCount()){
                            mProgress.dismiss();
                            utils.showtoast("All Product Quantity Updated");
                            progressCount = 0;
                            getSyncTime();
                        }
                    } else {
                        progressCount--;
                    }
                    try {
                        JSONArray j = new JSONArray(response);

                        // Parse a json
                        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = j.getJSONObject(0);
                                String code = String.valueOf(obj.get("code"));
                                Log.e("CODE", "" + code);

                                if(code.equals("1")){

                                }
                                if(code.equals("0")){

                                 utils.showtoast(""+obj.get("message"));

                                }
                                if(code.equals("-2")){
                                utils.showtoast(""+obj.get("message"));


                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error: ", "" + error.getMessage());
            utils.showtoast("Please try again...");


        }
    });
    eventoReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    // Añade la peticion a la cola
    AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(eventoReq);

}
```

Comment: What i'm doing here is I'm getting Data from Sqlite DataBase At Same time i'm passing value as an argument bymethod and calling API , within 2-3 seconds it will update all data to server.

Comment: You are sending data by url. But I use variable on web server which receive data on them post by me from Android application.

Comment: You are sending data by url. But I use variable on web server which receive data on them post by me from Android application.

Comment: Are you using API , POST request ?@MuhammadZeeshan

Answer (score 0):

Request to server inside a loop is not a good choice. Your loop can execute 1000 or more time. Try single request with array or list of post data.

Use [JsonArrayRequest](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java) for your request.It accepts `JSONArray` as parameter. From Volley Source Code:

```
/**
 * Creates a new request.
 * @param method the HTTP method to use
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONArray} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
 *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
 */
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest,
                        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
            errorListener);
}
```

> @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONArray} to post with the request. Null is allowed and

This constructor takes `JSONArray` which you can use to post your data. Make a `JSONArray` with your data and send request.

**Edit:**

Create your `JSONArray` like this:

```
JSONObject json1= new JSONObject();
json1.put("key1","value1");
json1.put("key2","value2");

JSONObject json2= new JSONObject();
json2.put("key1","value1");
json2.put("key2","value2");

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(json1);
jsonArray.put(json2);
```

Send Request with

```
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                return headers;
            }
        };
```

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32775920/1292557)

Comment: It gives me errors. and Seriously i didint get your answer . can you please tell me with respective code. ?

Comment: if you don't put your errors here how someone will help you what is the problem actually. Anyway i have updated my answer

Comment: I think i am getting your answer..But can you tell me where i write the code or make json array .  i have to make the json from SQLITE Database.