# Android Volley: POST request - req.body inside of NodeJS REST API empty

Tags: android, node.js, rest, express, android-volley

I know its been discussed like a billion times, and I have read a couple of questions/answers and this one in particular seemed like a good example -> [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414652/volley-jsonobjectrequest-post-request-ignoring-params). So now I have tried to recreate the code and added my `getParams()` as well as my `getHeaders()`.
Awkwardly I get a HTTP Status Code 400:

`E/Volley: [303] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.0.2.2:3000/classes`

Since I have created the REST API I can see where this status code 400 comes from, its my NodeJS response if the `req.body` doesn't contain `mAtt, mDatum, mRID, mVon`. So now I know that my `POST` request is not properly working even tho I set my `getParams()`as well as my `getHeaders()` ...

Now, my guess would be that I'm setting Params but I'm fetching `req.body.mAtt, req.body.mDatum , req.body.mRID, req.body.mVon`, that would explain why my NodeJS returns the status code 400. If I fetched `req.query.mAtt` I would probably get something back?

Is there a certain method that need to be overridden by me, to actually set the body instead of the query params?

This is what my POST req looks like:

```
    JsonObjectRequest JOPR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                       myAcitveLessonPOSTUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mAtt", "+1");
            params.put("mDatum", mDatum);
            params.put("mRID", mRID);
            params.put("mVon", mVon);

            return params;
        }


    };


    requestQ.add(JOPR);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a JSON body parsing Express middleware (e.g. `body-parser`)?

Comment: @mscdex yes I am, I'm using Express 4 and the `body-parser`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it. I continued to search for answers and stumbled upon this question/answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910502/android-volley-jsonobjectrequest-not-send-params).

Since my REST API is looking for `req.body` variables, the `getParams()` have no effect. In order to send `req.body` variables the `getBody()` method has to be overridden.

So what I basically had to do was:

1) create a JSONObject

2) put my key:values inside the JSONObject

3) get the contents of my JSONObject into a String via `toString()`

4) `@Override` the `getBody()` method inside my JsonObjectRequest

Done.

So my corrected code looks like this:

```
    JSONObject jsonBodyObj = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jsonBodyObj.put("mAtt", "+1");
        jsonBodyObj.put("mDatum",mDatum);
        jsonBodyObj.put("mRID",mRID);
        jsonBodyObj.put("mVon",mVon);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String requestBody = jsonBodyObj.toString();

    JsonObjectRequest JOPR = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                   myAcitveLessonPOSTUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                populateLessonDetails(myActiveLessonURLFiltered);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }


        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                        requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }


    };

    requestQ.add(JOPR);
```

Kudos to @dvdciri for his original question and Edits, what would eventually become this answer!