# Params not sent from android to node.js using Volley

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, express

I am creating an app which uses some node.js scripts for server scripting mainly because node.js has `Firebase` support, but for some reason I am unable to send any params with my request (both GET and POST).

My android code is as follows

```
private void sendData(final String name){
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString()+" returned from node.js server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString()+"The Server returned error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("test",name);
            return map;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue r = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    r.add(sr);
}
```

The corresponding node.js script is as follows

```
app.get('/hello', function(request, response){
  var outputJson = request.params.test;
  response.send(JSON.stringify(outputJson));
  console.log(outputJson);
})
```

The console always logs undefined for some reason. Following suggestions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708276/android-volley-post-request-req-body-inside-of-nodejs-rest-api-empty) I also tried including the data in the body of the request and get the data from the request in the node.js via `request.body.test`.

I would like to know what is going wrong and most importantly I would also like to know how to recieve and process `POST` request. I read on some blog that I have to implement a `middleware` of some kind. Some clarification in that area will also be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `/hello/:test` ?

Comment: https://sfbpush.herokuapp.com/hello/:test=xxx. I used this in a debugger and it still didn't return anything

Comment: how about trying to get your params using `request.param('test')`? but before that please try to just use `hello/:test` in your route

Comment: https://sfbpush.herokuapp.com/hello?test=xxx works with `request.param('test)` but when I call it from android it is not working. I tested it with REST debugger

Comment: no I tried adding the route too but still not working

Comment: check your `sr` output.

Comment: By sr do you mean the Console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133201/discussion-between-roljhon-and-tyson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked at your code and found that there are some flaws in the `Android` Code.

1. The HashMap is defined in a `getHeaders()` function but it should actually be defined in `getParams()` like this

   ```
    @Override
               public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                   HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                   map.put("test",name);
                   return map;
               }
   ```
2. Instead of trying to retrieve the data by `request.params` try using `request.body`.

Comment: by doing a request.body in node, he needs to override the getBody() in his android code if that is the case since if not, that would throw an undefined object property, request.params will be enough I believed

Comment: I too thought of it. That would have been my second guess if the post was not accepted. But apparently it got solved

Comment: the answer wasn't accepted yet, anyway, your answers is still helpful. :)

Comment: Oops. I got a reputation change and assumed it was due to this question. Thanks for bringing that to my attention.