# Android Volley: how to make json request without returned object?

Tags: android, json, jersey, android-volley

Now I'm doing

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, uri, json,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        // do action
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //manage error
                    }
                }
        );
```

My servlet uses Jersey as JAX-RS.
The resource called by the uri passed as parameter does not produce any json object. If I do this way, the error callback is called even if the json object sent with POST is correctly used on server.
If I return a json with fake data then the response callback is called, but I don't need to send back an object (wasting the user's data bandwidth). I'd like to do the normale response action if the code of response is OK or 200.
How should I do?

Comment: Could you provide the JSON responses that you are getting.

Comment: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: in my servlet it's a void type method, with no @Produces annotation

Comment: Then you can avoid using JsonObjectRequest altogether.

Comment: How to post a json without a jsonobjectRequest?

Comment: I need to send an object and wait for OK code or an error

Comment: You can use StringRequest instead. Pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197615/volley-send-jsonobject-to-server-with-post-method.

Comment: No I can't, because the problem is the same, I would have to produce an unnecessary string

Comment: Ah, I see. So you can override deliverReponse, perhaps with empty content. Read more at http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the parseNetworkResponse method of JsonObjectRequest so that it accepts null responses:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, uri, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    // do action
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    //manage error
                }
            }
        ) {

        @Override
        protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {


            try {
                String json = new String(
                        response.data,
                        "UTF-8"
                );

                if (json.length() == 0) {
                    return Response.success(
                            null,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)
                    );
                }
                else {
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
            }


        }
    };
```